# How to show that $\sqrt{1+ni}=\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)\right)+i\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, radicals

Wolfram Alpha gives me that 
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+i}&=\sqrt[4]{2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(1)\right)+i\sqrt[4]{2}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(1)\right)\\
&=\sqrt[4]{2}e^{\frac{1}{2}i\tan^{-1}(1)}\\
\sqrt{1+2i}&=\sqrt[4]{5}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(2)\right)+i\sqrt[4]{5}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(2)\right)\\
&=\sqrt[4]{5}e^{\frac{1}{2}i\tan^{-1}(2)}\\
\sqrt{1+3i}&=\sqrt[4]{10}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(3)\right)+i\sqrt[4]{10}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(3)\right)\\
&=\sqrt[4]{10}e^{\frac{1}{2}i\tan^{-1}(3)}
\end{align}$$
In general, how can we show that
$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+ni}&=\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)\right)+i\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)\right)\\
&=\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}e^{\frac{1}{2}i\tan^{-1}(n)}
\end{align}$$

I tried to draw a complex plane, but it did not help significantly. Perhaps I forgot some fundamental concepts. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: write $1+i n$ in polar form, that is as $r \exp(i\phi)$. What is $r$, what is $\phi$?

Comment: Thanks Fabian, I think I have figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the polar form $$z=\sqrt{n^2+1}\,e^{i\arctan n}$$ you draw

$$\sqrt z=\pm\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\,e^{i\arctan n\,/2}.$$

Then back to Cartesian coordinates,

$$\pm\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\left(\cos\frac{\arctan n}2+i\sin\frac{\arctan n}2\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
z&=1+ni,~r=\sqrt{n^2+1}\\
1+ni &=\sqrt{n^2+1}\cos(\tan^{-1}(n))+i\sqrt{n^2+1}\sin(\tan^{-1}(n))\\
&= \sqrt{n^2+1}e^{i\tan^{-1}(n)}\\
\sqrt{1+ni}&=\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}e^{\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)}\\
&=\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)\right)+i\sqrt[4]{n^2+1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1}(n)\right)
\end{align}$$